# insert obj into array

Tags: python, object

I have a class

```
class simple:
    name=""
    number=0

classArray=[]

for i in range(10):
    a=simple

    a.name="say that I got something from database"
    a.number="same thing from database"

    classArray.append(a)


    print(classArray[i].name)
```

whenever I try to index an element from the array it's always the last one that I've inserted

the name will be always the same

Answer (score 0):

To create object of class you have to call class a = simple()

```
class simple:
    name=""
    number=0

classArray=[]

for i in range(10):
    a=simple()

    a.name="say that I got something from database"
    a.number="same thing from database"

    classArray.append(a)
    print(classArray[i].name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your `simple` class to create an instance of it.

Change:

```
a=simple
```

to:

```
a=simple()
```